# Retrieve data dynamically from pivot SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, pivot

Asmx Code:

```
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                HBPivot_cs thpivot = new HBPivot_cs();
                thpivot.EMPLOYEEID = rdr["EMPLOYEEID"].ToString();
                thpivot.FIRSTDATE = rdr["06/26/2018"].ToString();
                thpivot.SECONDDATE = rdr["06/27/2018"].ToString();
                listhbpivot.Add(thpivot);
            }
            con.Close();
```

My Data :
This data is result from Pivot

```
EMPLOYEEID     06/26/2018     06/27/2018     06/28/2018     06/29/2018
1              07:00 AM       08:00 AM       07:30 AM       10:00 AM
2              07:01 AM       08:20 AM       07:10 AM       06:00 AM
```

The fieldname are dynamic... how can i retrieve it using rdr.read
Thanks

Comment: You can use index `rdr[1].ToString();`, `rdr[2].ToString();`

Comment: what about passing it to list?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the following stored procedure in your sql server database.

   ```
   create procedure dbo.EmploeeDynamicPivot
   as
   begin

       set nocount on;

       declare
           @columns    as nvarchar(max),
           @query      as nvarchar(max)

       select
           @columns    =
           stuff
           ((
                   select
                   distinct
                       ',' + quotename([your_date_column]) 
                   from
                       [your_table]
                   for xml path(''), type
           ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')


       set @query =
       'select
           EMPLOYEEID, ' + @columns + '
       from 
       (
           select
               EMPLOYEEID   ,
               [your_date_column]   ,
               [your_value_column]
           from
               [your_table]
       )
           sourceTable
       pivot 
       (
           sum([your_value_column])
           for [your_date_column] in (' + @columns + ')
       )
           pivotTable'


       execute(@query);

       set nocount off;

   end
   ```
2. edit your c# code by the following code.

   ```
   var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection([your_connection_string]);

   sqlConnection.Open();

   var sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

   sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   sqlCommand.CommandText = "EmploeeDynamicPivot";

   var rdr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

   while (rdr.Read())
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
       {
           var value = rdr.GetString(i);
           or
           var value = rdr.GetValue(i);

           //do something... 
       }
   }
   ...
   ```

Comment: how about using rdr

Comment: use index instead column name. for example rdr.GetString(0) 0 stands for the first column.

Comment: while (rdr.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        var value = rdr.GetString(i);
 or
 var value = rdr.GetValue(i);

        //do something...
    }
}

Comment: please explain more about your problem. the query is dynamic and return fieldnames.

Comment: please look to "My Data" i want to show just like that... if someone added new Date it also dynamically add the new Date

Comment: the query shows columns for each date in rows. for example if there is 9 rows then you have 9 columns or there is 20 then shows 20 columns.

Comment: please replace [your_table], [your_date_column] and [your_value_column] in sql code with your names.